# Using the Volley API how would I parse this low level JSON to get this url

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I cut out a lot of the unimportant stuff to keep this simple. I just want the url property.

```
{
"meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK"
},
"response": {
    "posts": [
        {
            "photos": [
                {
                    "original_size": {
                        "url": "LINK",
                        "width": 612,
                        "height": 612
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String json = "...";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject respObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray posts = respObj.getJSONArray("posts");
        JSONObject firstPost = (JSONObject) posts.get(0);
        JSONArray photos = firstPost.getJSONArray("photos");
        JSONObject firstPhoto = (JSONObject) photos.get(0);
        JSONObject photoSize = firstPhoto.getJSONObject("original_size");
        String url = photoSize.getString("url");
        Log.e("URL:", url );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```